# Implementing jstl.jar in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jstl

I have a dynamic web application project in eclipse and I'm trying to use jstl in my jsp.

I've added:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

on the beginning of my .jsp file and declared

```
<c:if test="${empty user_id}"></c:if>
```

And recieved no complains from eclipse. But when I deplay and run the application in Tomcat. I receive this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/TagLibraryValidator
```

I've downloaded jstl-1.2.jar and added it to the tomcat lib folder and it shows up togheter with the other .jar files in Libraries->Apache Tomcat 7.0
I've also added the jstl-1.2.jar file to the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ folder. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Okay the javax.servlet.jsp package under apache tomcat lib is empty. How  do I import the jstl-1.2.jar in it?

Comment: Follow the installation guide from [StackOverflow JSTL wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)

Comment: Add the jar to only *one* of those places.